# Image is re-downloaded after every keystroke

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [While making a post with an image, the image flickers in and out of the preview while I type](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100557/while-making-a-post-with-an-image-the-image-flickers-in-and-out-of-the-preview-w)

Kind of a minor issue, but in one of my posts earlier on SU I inserted an image while I was writing my question so I could make my point clearer. After the image had been inserted after every keypress the image was re-downloaded (as shown in my IE Status Bar.) [image]

Just a minor one.

(IE8, Windows 7, 32-Bit). Seen on M.SO and SU.)

Comment: In the YouTube video from [that other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100557/while-making-a-post-with-an-image-the-image-flickers-in-and-out-of-the-preview-w), I do not see the Chrome network/download indicator turning around. But it might still be related indeed. Tombull, can you test with Safari or Chrome (for their WebKit Web Inspector), or in Firefox with the Firebug add-on, to check if you see network activity?

Comment: (Tombul, see [the network panel](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/network.html) in Chrome's developer tools, a.k.a. Web Inspector in Safari. That will also allow you to see the HTTP headers. Also note `chrome://view-http-cache/http://i.stack.imgur.com/cmXJg.png` in Chrome.)

Comment: @Arjan, I've checked with the latest version of FireFox with FireBug and have been unable to reproduce (although possible I've been looking in the wrong place :/).

Comment: When looking at [Firebug's Net panel](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel), and then expanding the row that fetches [the image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cmXJg.png) (hit Ctrl-F5 to reload, if you don't see that row, or if it says `304 Not Modified`), do you see (kind of) the same `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers [that Web-Sniffer gets](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FcmXJg.png)?

Comment: (As an aside: Firefox and Firebug don't need CamelCase spelling.)

Comment: @Arjan, both FireBug and Cache-Control both report "control" and "expires" headers of `max-age=31536000` and `Thu, 23 Aug 2012 08:02:50 GMT` (save a few seconds).

Answer (score 6):

As you make changes to the post, the Markdown preview is completely (and intentionally) rerendered on the fly. This means that the image is reinserted into the DOM many times over, so the browser does have to pull up the image more than once.

Typically the image will be in the cache after the first load though, so it shouldn't have to make an actual request for it on subsequent updates, and the process shouldn't be noticeable. I *was* finally able to reproduce this, but I had to use Fiddler to deliberately create the scenario (and even then I had trouble for a bit, for some reason).

Comment: Indeed, the image [should be in the cache](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FcmXJg.png) for 31,536,000 seconds (being 1 year). Are you using some InPrivate mode, Tombull?

Comment: @Arjan, nope. Normal IE (no InPrivate or no-add-on mode)

Comment: Very odd, @tombull89. When downloaded once, I see no network activity whatsoever in Chrome's web inspector when using `![Some diagram](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cmXJg.png)` and adding text above or below it. (Well, there's a heartbeat Ajax call, but that's all.)

Comment: @tombull89 You aren't behind any sort of proxy either, right?

Comment: Tim, did you disable caching using Fiddler? @tombull, I guess not as much more would probably break, but: any chance your clock is one year fast...?

Comment: @Arjan Yeah, I did.

Comment: @Tim Stone, nope, no proxy.

Comment: @Arjan, nope I'm not in the future either.